# jQuery how to load a div from a other page using load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little project where I need to show items on one page from a other so I have a little categorie where you can click on. Then I pick the `attr("href");` and set that to the page I would like to load. this works.
But how to add a `<div>` to it so I online load like the `<div class="holder"></div>` And not the whole div?
This is my function:

```
function setupCasesFilter() 
{       
    j(".casemenu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        j("ul.casesholder").load(j(this).attr("href")); 
    });
}
```

Where I can add the class inside `attr("href"));` ?

Comment: please explain better what you are trying to achieve! I have read your question about 4-5 times and still don't understand what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: K, if you click on a anker, The href will be my parameter to load a other page inside a div on my current page. With e.preventdefault(); I make sure he won't go to that page But stay on the current page. Now i want to load of that page just 1 div. And not the hole page what i now have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load a specific div element from the url then use it this way:

```
j("ul.casesholder").load(j(this).attr("href") + " .holder");
```

---

What seems to me that you have a `.holder` div on the `href` page you are loading, so you can pass that div's class name which you want to load with a space for ex. `page.html .holder`.